# Is the Downton Abbey viewing order question on topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, questions, scope

Is the following question on topic?

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9552/downton-abbey-christmas-special-order

It is about the viewing order of a series with a very limited number of chronologically ordered episodes per season. It is *trivial* to locate the episode guides on both [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Downton_Abbey_episodes) and [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1606375/episodes?season=3&ref_=tt_eps_sn_3), and the questioner has answered his own question (after a few minutes of asking it) by simply quoting WP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say no.

Just like the *OP* proved when answering his own question (only 5 minutes later!), the answer can be found almost instantaneously by doing a quick search for it or just heading straight over to *IMDb* to have a look at the episode list.